# insert clob datatypefrom sql server

Tags: plsql, clob

I have the below code to insert clob datatype from SQL server to Oracle Database using DBlink.
I m currently facing the error : 
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: invalid LOB locator specified: ORA-22275
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_LOB", line 639. Can you please help me what could be the issue with the code?

```
 declare
  v_REGION_CODE CLOB  ; 
 l_clob CLOB;
 c integer;
 nr integer;
 BEGIN
 DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(l_clob,true);
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE SVQ_DI_XLS_COUNTRY_POP_DETAILS';
c := DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.OPEN_CURSOR@PPRLEG;
DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.PARSE@PPRLEG(c,' SELECT "REGION CODE" FROM TBL_SVQ_DI_XLS_COUNTRY_POP_DETAILS');
LOOP
  nr := DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.FETCH_ROW@PPRLEG(c);
  EXIT
WHEN nr = 0;

 DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.GET_VALUE@PPRLEG(c,    1   ,   v_REGION_CODE ) ;

FOR i IN 1..10
LOOP
  INSERT INTO SVQ_DI_XLS_COUNTRY_POP_DETAILS (REGION_CODE) VALUES    (empty_clob()) --Insert an "empty clob" (not insert null)
RETURNING REGION_CODE INTO l_clob;

  FOR i IN 1..100
LOOP
  dbms_lob.append(l_clob, v_REGION_CODE);
  --dbms_lob.append(l_clob, 'string chunk to be inserted (maximum 4000     characters at a time)');
END LOOP;
END LOOP;`enter code here`
END LOOP;
 DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.CLOSE_CURSOR@PPRLEG(c);
COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: You don't state the database versions. The error should show the line in your code, where the execution stopped.

Comment: Oracle DB version is 12 c and SQL server is SQL Management Studio 2005.The error is at this line dbms_lob.append(l_clob, v_REGION_CODE). My aim is to insert clob data from SQL server to Oracle Database which are also of clob datatypes

Comment: I think you can get that error at dbms_lob.append if v_region_code is null - in which case you don't need to append. See the exception section of https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_lob.htm#ARPLS66624.